# What does the intro of Nocturnal Animals mean?

Tags: analysis, nocturnal-animals

In the intro of the movie "Nocturnal Animals" what do the naked women and their unusual makeup represent?

[image]

Comment: Highly related quote found in this related answer - http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68522/what-is-the-significance-of-buttocks?rq=1

Answer (score 7):

I think that the opening scene is there to make this powerful contrast between the women that are nothing that our society expects them to be but are truly happy, joyful, celebrating and enjoying themselves, and Susan that is everything that our society says she should be but is still so unhappy.